# Silverlight - Do not set page title

Tags: silverlight, navigation, page-title

I have a Silverlight navigation application. I don't want navigation in this application to change the host page's Title property.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solutions that I found were to either set the title on every navigation page or use a base class for all the navigation pages and set the title on it. You could possibly manage your own Journal (which would prevent it from setting) but that would be a lot of work. Here is the relevant code in the NavigationService.

```
if (this.Journal.UseNavigationState && HtmlPage.IsEnabled)
{
    HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("title", name ?? ((uriBeforeMapping == null) ? string.Empty : uriBeforeMapping.OriginalString));
}
```